# python: capture docstring as an exact match using regex

Tags: python, regex, match

Say I have the following function

```
def func(self, arg1=None, arg2=None):
    """
    Returns the product for the specified arg1 and arg2.
    Args:
        arg1: argument 1
        arg2: argument 2
    Returns:
        product of arg1 for arg2.

    DAL Owner: Team IT
    Data Owner: Team A
    """
    return arg1*arg2
```

I have need to match only whatever is inside the triple quotations. I have been able to do match it as a group using the following regex

```
def func.*?\):.*?\"\"\"(.*)\"\"\"
```

But it does not allow me to string replace easily in python. So I have a need to capture the docstring as a match instead of a group. I tried lookbehind `(?<=def f2)` but then ran into the variable length not allowed in lookbehind problem. Any ideas as to how to go about this will be deeply appreciated.

**UPDATE**:

I really would like to know if this can be done with an exact match i.e. not having to use multiple capturing groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match *only* the portion inside the `"""`s, one option is to use the [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module, which has support for the `\K` token, which effectively forgets everything that was previously matched. Utilize this by matching (normally) the `def func` up until the `"""`s, then use `\K` to reset the starting point of the match to the current position, then lazy-repeat any character until lookahead matches another `"""`:

```
import regex
input  = '''
def func(self, arg1=None, arg2=None):
    """
    Returns the product for the specified arg1 and arg2.
    Args:
        arg1: argument 1
        arg2: argument 2
    Returns:
        product of arg1 for arg2.

    DAL Owner: Team IT
    Data Owner: Team A
    """
    return arg1*arg2
'''
replaced = regex.sub(r'(?s)def func\(.*?"""\K.*?(?=""")', 'replacement', input)
print(replaced)
```

Output:

```
def func(self, arg1=None, arg2=None):
    """replacement"""
    return arg1*arg2
```

`\K`, when available, can be a more flexible replacement for lookbehind.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to replace easily, you capture *everything else* into groups:

```
(def func.*?\):.*?\"\"\").*(\"\"\")
```

Then to replace, you just write `$1xxx$2` as the replacement, with `xxx` being the actual replacement you want.

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/sNqaCR/1).

Comment: I have thought of this but would rather like to avoid having groups. Reason being that my matching will not always have the same groups

Comment: @Fizi Can you edit the question to show a situation where the solution is not applicable?